# div, that fills the viewport height at least minus a margin

Tags: html, css

[image]

I think the two states shown in the image are self-explanatory. The red lines have the same height, the blue bars have the same dimensions.
How can I achieve this layout? My attempt so far (may be used for testing): http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/

The doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` but could be changed to `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

**The problem** is, that I see no way to keep the red line the same height when the content gets bigger while still having *no scrollbar* when the content is small enough.

**The restrictions** are only, that I do not want to use anything that is supported by less than 90% of the users. For example `box-sizing` luckily is [supported by ~93% of the users](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

EDIT: I need a `box-shadow` on the black area, so overlays will not solve the problem. But besides this, Nulen made a working example (http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/2/) of how it shall behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it dirty way with black divs as black margins with content like this:

```
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0 70px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/2/
modify height of #inside div to test for different content.

EDIT: done with `calc()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/9/

EDIT: done with `overflow: auto;`:
http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/10/
(note: this does not work entirely for my IE11) //nulen

Comment: You understand what i want! But its too dirty, I need it to work with a box-shadow on the `#content`...

Comment: `box-shadow` as well as `calc()` is not supported by 90% of browsers, but if you can use `calc()` here is how it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/6/

Comment: nah.. that does not look right in my firefox 30.0, there is no space at the end of the page. Also the `box-shadow` will only be shown by those who support it, that is okay, it is not part of the structure.

Comment: So hack it a little bit dirty to work everywhere like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/8/ (and if you ignore older mobile browsers it is supported by enough)

Comment: This is a correct answer, thanks for the input :) (I added my own solution to it, since it seems there is more than one way to do it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you require but give this a try

```
#foot { position:fixed;left:100px;}
#content {height:500px;overflow:hidden;
```

You will need to put `position:relative` around the containing div and also change the height accordingly on content div.

Comment: No, this is not what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would wrap the actual content in a container that is set up to scroll. That way you can control the wrapper's height, and its content will scroll within it.

```
<div id="#bodyContent">
    <div id="#wrapperThatScrolls" style="overflow-y:auto" >
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    // Your red margin would appear here
</div>
```

Comment: The hint `overflow` did it. I got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/n6zYE/7/ . But your answer does not really make sense to me. Please have a look at the scroll bar in example **B**. Either that scroll bar looks to you like it was inside the content element, *which it is not meant to be* **or** you have not articulated yourself very well **or** I simply do not understand, what you mean. So either you have to add an explanation, why my fiddle works so I can check this as answer or I have to self-answer my question...

Answer (score 0):

Solution, using `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`:

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body {
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#inside {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 200px;    
}
#topcontentrow, #bottomcontentrow {
  display: table-row;
  height: 20px;
}
#contentrow {
  display: table-row;
  background: grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000;
}
#content {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: white;
}
#contenttable {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#foot {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: -60px auto 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenttable">
  <div id="topcontentrow"></div>
  <div id="contentrow">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="inside">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomcontentrow"></div>
</div>
<div id="foot">
</div>
```

Tested and working in FF 31.0 and IE 11
The `display: table` is [supported widely](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).